# Help with 12.04 and windows 8.1 homegroup?

Tags: 12.04, windows

i`m new to ubuntu and i would like to connect my ubuntu laptop to my main pc via windows homegroup. is it possible or i need to make a server on ubuntu or pc ?
and if you have solution - explain me step by step :)

Answer (score 0):

If your point is only file sharing from Windows to Ubuntu via LAN.You just simply share the folder on the Network,make it accessible from LAN.

And don't forget to set your sharing setting that make it accessible for all computer
[image]